ImportError: cannot import name '_request_ctx_stack' from 'flask'
I am new to Python and flask framework when I am using flask I am getting "ImportError: cannot import name '_request_ctx_stack' from flask
I have tried executing the following commands

pip install --upgrade setuptools -->It executed smoothely
pip install --upgrade distribute -->It ended by giving following error

Collecting distribute
  Using cached distribute-0.7.3.zip (145 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Installing backend dependencies ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [6 lines of output]
      usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
         or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
         or: setup.py --help-commands
         or: setup.py cmd --help

      error: invalid command 'dist_info'
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.

First when I am trying to import the RoleMixin from flask-security I got the error as
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Python Practice\Role Based Access Control\script.py", line 1, in <module>
    from app import app 
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "E:\Python Practice\Role Based Access Control\app\__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from app import routes
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "E:\Python Practice\Role Based Access Control\app\routes.py", line 6, in <module>
    from app.models import User, Role
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "E:\Python Practice\Role Based Access Control\app\models.py", line 3, in <module>
    from flask_security import RoleMixin
  File "E:\Python Practice\Role Based Access Control\myenv\Lib\site-packages\flask_security\__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    from .core import (
  File "E:\Python Practice\Role Based Access Control\myenv\Lib\site-packages\flask_security\core.py", line 86, in <module>
    from .totp import Totp
  File "E:\Python Practice\Role Based Access Control\myenv\Lib\site-packages\flask_security\totp.py", line 18, in <module>
    from passlib.pwd import genword
  File "E:\Python Practice\Role Based Access Control\myenv\Lib\site-packages\passlib\pwd.py", line 16, in <module>
    import pkg_resources
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pkg_resources'

To resolve this I used "pip install --upgrade setuptools"
after executing this if run my script I am getting
ImportError: cannot import name '_request_ctx_stack' from 'flask'


Why are you attempting to install distribute? It's a legacy package that's last released over a decade ago.

Please show the original traceback leading to your ImportError: cannot import name '_request_ctx_stack' from flask exception, and the relevant code.

flask-security version is incompatible with flask and there are no recent releases in flask-security alternative for this is install "Flask-Security-Too"
and you can import the required modules from "flask_security"
You can try the below link for additional reference
https://flask-security-too.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart.html
